# Search for String in both elements of pairs

Tags: haskell

Again I am stuck.
I have a list of pairs of strings `[(String, String)]` and want to look for another String in it.
When the substring matches the first in the tuple, I'd like to return the second one and vice versa.

I had some ideas but again, I don't know how to correctly apply functions in Haskell.
My first idea was to use `map` but that wouldn't really be able to give me a String as a result, would it?

I was thinking about using `filter`. First searching the substring in the first of the pair and then in the second ones.
This is as far as I got:

```
search :: String -> [(String, String)] -> String
search substr xs = filter(==substr) xs.fst
```

And it doesn't even work :/

I'd be thankful for any kind of advice!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to wrap the return type in `Maybe` in case the substring isn't found.

```
search :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> Maybe a
search s xs = case lookup s xs of
                Just x -> Just x
                Nothing -> lookup s xs'
    where xs' = map swap xs
```

If you don't want to wrap it with `Maybe`, just use the `fromJust` function and change the type signature accordingly. In the above code, you are using the library defined `lookup` function. And in case the lookup fails in the first search you exchange the tuples and again perform the `lookup` operation. Also, Don't forget to import `swap` from `Data.Tuple`.

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci > let a = [("hi","bye"),("cat", "dog")]
ghci > search "hi" a
Just "bye"
ghci > search "dog" a
Just "cat"
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I'd like to return a default string in case nothing is found? And what exactly does the apostrophe do?`

Comment: @Ingo, Thanks, generalized it. @Henry, Pattern match on `Nothing` and return the default string you want to return. Apostrophe does nothing special. It is just another variable related to `xs`.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `lookup` on the list, and then call lookup after swapping each tuple in the list. But this means possibly traversing the list twice.

```
lookup' k = foldl acc Nothing
    where 
        acc (Just x) _ = Just x
        acc _ (a,b)    | k == b = Just a | k == a = Just b | otherwise = Nothing
```

This way you traverse the list only once. This version doesn't terminate on infinite lists if the element is present. You can write it using foldr, but that for that version, `lookup' 0 [(0,1), undefined] == undefined` as opposed to the preferred behavior.

You can also write it using explicit recursion. For once, using explicit recursion is better! It covers both of the cases covered above:

```
lookup'' k [] = Nothing
lookup'' k ((a,b):xs)  
    | k == a = Just b
    | k == b = Just a
    | otherwise = lookup'' k xs

>lookup'' 1 [(1,0), undefined]
Just 0
>lookup'' 1 (zip [0..] [0..])
Just 1
```

Comment: Indeed. In fact the `map swap` version traverses the list three times if the element isn't present!

Comment: `lookup'` does not terminate if given an infinite list of tuples, even if `k` is found, whereas `lookup''` does.

Answer (score 1):

user2407038's solution, `lookup''` is the most efficient since it traverses the list only once, and terminates early when a match is found.  It can be written without explicit recursion as follows:

```
import Control.Monad ( msum )

lookup'' k = msum . map match
  where match (a, b) | k == a = Just b
                     | k == b = Just a
                     | otherwise = Nothing
```